# How to set maxFileSize in Essential.Diagnostics.RollingFileTraceListener

Tags: c#, logging, system.diagnostics, diagnostics, rollingfileappender

Can someone please let me know how to set MaxSize for log file in Essential.Diagnostics.RollingFileTraceListener. Here is my config

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="filelog" type="Essential.Diagnostics.RollingFileTraceListener, Essential.Diagnostics"
           initializeData="C:\Team\LogFiles\{ApplicationName}-{DateTime:MMddyyyy}.log"
           template="[{DateTime:MM-dd-yyyy HH':'mm':'ss}] [{MachineName}] {EventType} {Source} : {Message}{Data}"/>
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true">
      <listeners>
        <clear />
        <add name="filelog" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

As the [documentation for RollingFileTraceListener](https://essentialdiagnostics.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=RollingFileTraceListener) states:

> A trace listener that writes to a text file, rolling to a new file based on a filename template (usually including the date).
>
> …
>
> A rolling log file is achieved by including the date in the filename, so that when the date changes a different file is used.

Unlike log4net's RollingFileAppender which rolls files "based on size or date or both", then, this component only rolls by date.

(You can also [inspect the code](https://essentialdiagnostics.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Essential.Diagnostics/Diagnostics/RollingFileTraceListener.cs) and see that there are no properties relating to file size)

Comment: Can this be done problematically then. I mean can i write code in c# instead of having configuration file and create new file when threshold reaches.

Comment: You would need to do it manually - or extend the existing class - as there is currently no support for rolling these files by size.